# Check if directory paths are the same

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to evaluate whether 2 strings refer to the same directory or not (doing a simple comparison is not good enough due to possible virtual links, etc...)

I have looked into `filecmp`, but `filecmp.cmp` seems to work only for files, not directories. `filecmp.dircmp` does not seem to exactly fit my purpose.

Therefore, I am currently doing it this way:

```
if os.path.realpath(old_path) == os.path.realpath(new_path):
    raise ValueError('Need different path!')
```

Does anyone have a better idea? Is there any edge case in which this would not work?

Answer (score 0):

A possible edge case would be stuff like multiple mount points/bind mounts. If you have access to a Linux machine, try as root:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/a /tmp/b /tmp/c
$ mount --bind /tmp/c /tmp/a
$ mount --bind /tmp/c /tmp/b
```

The /tmp/a and /tmp/b paths now refer to the same directory:

```
$ echo 'Hello' > /tmp/a/file.txt
$ cat /tmp/b/file.txt
Hello
```

Whether or not that is a problem in your case is hard to tell without knowing *why* you want to check this equality. If it's just a sanity check, your original comparison seems very reasonable.

Otherwise, if your platform supports it, you could try comparing inode numbers using [os.stat()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.stat). Identical directories should have identical inode numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have ideas on how to make the function more robust for the example you highlight?